# How mypy handles Django ORM field definition

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, mypy

I've defined a new type of field in Django called `TruncatingCharField` which is a subclass of `CharField`. When running mypy on

```
firebase_identifier = TruncatingCharField(max_length=FIREBASE_IDENTIFIER_MAX_LENGTH, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)
```

...

```
if not user_profile.firebase_identifier:
   user_profile.firebase_identifier = firebase_identifier <-- Error
   user_profile.save()
```

I'm getting the following error on the marked line `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "TruncatingCharField")`

Only when adding `:str` type hinting to the field definition the error clears. It does not happen on other fields.

Am I missing something ?